# C++ NetBeans Win32 hwnd icon

Tags: c++, winapi, netbeans, icons

I am having difficulties with adding an icon to my application window in NetBeans. The code is Win32 related. Whenever I add my icon to the **resources folder (in the NetBeans IDE)** the *LoadImage()* or the *LoadIcon()* methods fail to retrieve the icon file, and the result I get is these screenshots:

[image]
[image]

So I am wondering, is there something wrong with the location I put the icon? If so, where could I put the icon in? (Project directories below):

[image]

If it has nothing to do with the location, or I am using the right location, could it be the code I am using? (Code below):

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;

//Step 1: Registering the Window Class
wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style         = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
```

Feed back would be VERY appreciated. I really want to know what is going on with this. Thanks.

-CA1K

***EDIT:*** The code shown above is set back to the usual, I am just trying to find ways to retrieve the icon file.

Comment: **I could be wrong, but** `LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION)` is documented as returning a standard icon provided by Windows, not the icon for your application. You will need to figure out how resources in your NetBeans project map to resources embedded in the executable ("Windows resources").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@andlabs is right. `IDI_APPLICATION` is defined in WinUser.h as:

```
#define IDI_APPLICATION MAKEINTRESOURCE(32512)
```

You need instead:

```
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON));
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALLICON));
```

Where you define `IDI_ICON` as a number:

```
#define IDI_ICON 1
```

And in resource.rc:

```
IDI_ICON ICON "icon.ico"
```

This will set the icon in taskbar. For the icon in title bar, use this in `WM_CREAT`:

```
HICON hicon = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON), 
    IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR | LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hicon);
```

### ----------------------------------------------------------

Edit:

For a simple test, try

In resource.rc file:

```
1 ICON "icon.ico"
```

In .cpp file:

```
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1));
```

Comment: I forgot to add `hInstance` or `GetModuleHandleW(NULL)`. See updated answer. It works in Netbeans, however I had a hard time with it, I had to clean/rebuild and then use the command `windres.exe resource.rc resource.o` and build again.